# How soon Apple crash report appears in iTunes Connect?

Tags: crash, app-store-connect

I've read a bunch of articles on Apple crash reporting tool. When users allow sharing their *Usage & Diagnostics* data with developers, user related logs and crash info will be sent to an Apple server and afterwards they will be available for the app developer via iTunes Connect or in Xcode Crashes Organizer window when setup correctly.

The question is how soon will this crash report be available for me as a developer. Is it done instantly? Can I get an email alert about the crash of my app?

Comment: I have nearly 5 years of iPhone Development under my belt and I have never seen a single crash come through iTunes Connect.  Even after many support tickets with Apple, they cannot explain why that is the case.  We just use third party crash reporting tools like Crashlytics or HockeyApp instead.

Comment: @TimReddy,  that is  very  helpful. So  I guess the answer is never? I  think we'll go with Crashlytics as well.